# How to make Android microphone input independent from speaker position?

Tags: android, microphone, android-audiomanager, android-audiorecord

I want to do some audio processing on my Android device using its microphone input. Unfortunately, the audio processing I am using is very sensitive to the distance (so basically the Loudness) between speaker and microphone and the phone positioning. How can the sensitivity of the Audio input to position/distance be reduced? Is it for example possible to normalize the input to give it always the same loudness?

Answer (score 1):

You can play a sound with a known "loudness". You can then record how loud the sound that you played is to know approximate distance to the speaker. This may also help overcome different volume levels of speakers and phones as well.